# I cannot connect Lumia 1320 to Windows 7 via USB

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

At work I have Windows 7 with all updates installed but I cannot connect my Nokia Lumia 1320 (Windows Phone 8.1 with all updates installed) via USB cable. I get this eror:

[image]

While trying to install the driver it gives errors. Also, Windows Update has suggested me to download a driver but when I try to install it gives me error that the instarctuns in the .inf file are not supported.

Comment: You probably need to talk to your IT department to install the driver ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, we don't have IT department. I am the administrator of my computer.

Comment: which error (code) do you get when you try to install the driver?

Comment: Close voter: phones are off-topic except when the issue involves connecting them to a computer, which is the case here.

Comment: @magicandre1981, no error code is given. It says "Did not repaired." http://i.imgur.com/az6LSNJ.png

Comment: I can't red this. Upload the file "C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Windows 8.1 N updated to Windows 10. No matter which device I wanted to connect (Lumia 1320, 640 or Adroid) I had an error in device manager. This solved my problem:

Media Feature Pack for "N" Windows version:
https://www.microsoft.com/pl-pl/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40744

Comment: Link to the english version of the page **https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40744**